# Problems hard to implement in functional programming

Tags: oop, functional-programming

Which problems which are easy to solve using OOP are hard to implement or uneffective using FP?

Comment: Try to multiply two matrices efficiently using pure FP. But, of course, OOP is pretty much useless for this task too.

Comment: SK-logic, http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa-algorithms/3.2.1.1/doc/html/src/Data-Array-Repa-Algorithms-Matrix.html#mmultP

Comment: @DonStewart, it is not a *pure*  functional code at all. See the definitions for all the `unsafe*` stuff.

Comment: Object-oriented programming and functional programming are orthogonal concepts. The "normal" complement of functional programming is imperative programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object hierarchies tend to be awkward in FP. Instead, you just use algebraic data types, which are far simpler.

Comment: Object hierarchy in FP is as useful as monads in OOP :)